# If the two tables are inner joined, what will be the output?

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
Table A: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4  
Table B: 1 1 2 2 3 3 5 5 5
```

What will be the output if the two tables are inner joined?

My answer was 1 1 2 2 3 3 but the interviewer said it wrong :/

According to my knowledge, inner join means the common factors of two tables. What should be my approach to this question?

Comment: What's the inner join condition?  Presumably (but not necessarily) an equality join?  Then you get a Cartesian product effect: 6 rows with 1, 4 rows with 2, 6 rows with 3 (none with 4 or 5). Each row in A matches each corresponding row in B.

Comment: Your definition is right, but I don't understand how those are even called table. Which are the attributes? And where the inner join is happening?

In that situation I would have answered like you.

Comment: "inner join means the common factors of two tables" - you should re-read what inner join is

Comment: "if the two tables are inner joined" doesn't make sense--an inner join comes with a condition that its result depends on. "the common factors of two tables" is unintelligible. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Give your DBMS & version. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Quote a definition of inner join from an authoritative source, apply it, and explain where you get stuck. Please don't ask us to write another one. Also it is nevertheless an easily found faq, and duplicate questions should not be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer will be :

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ba62908f4124dd5d755b7976d205658)

Let me explain for 1:
There are three rows containing 1 in TableA and two rows with 1 in TableB, so the final output will have 3*2 = six 1. Similarly for the other values.

Comment: The question is not clear, so it merits a comment asking for clarification, not a guess at an answer, guesses lead to messes. Also please put everything that a post needs to be understood in the post itself, not somewhere else that you link to.

Comment: @philipxy, in oracle db we need to give demo like this only

Comment: That comment is unintelligible. Please use enough words, sentences & references to things to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Have you read the question? But anyway, I appreciate that you are helping for good cause

Comment: Again: 1. INNER JOIN requires a condition via ON, USING or NATURAL but the question does not give any condition or column names. (The result has one column, so to be a join, rather than a projection of a join, it would have to be one of the latter 2.) You are guessing an answer to a question that is unclear & so should be commented on & closed. 2. Your post should be self-contained by having code, not a link. There is nothing in my comments inconsistent with the question or SO. [ask] [answer]

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what the query is.  If you do:

```
select *
from a join
     b
     on 1=0;
```

You will get no rows.

If you do:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on 1=1;
```

You will generate a Cartesian product.

If you do:

```
select *
from a join
     b
     on a.col = 4 and b.col = 2;
```

You will get 4 rows with `4 2` repeated four times.

If you do:

```
select *
from a join
     b
     on b.col^2 = a.col^3 + 1;
```

You will get four rows each with `2` and `3`.

And so on.

Your question doesn't have enough information.